# How Can i sort the elements inside Local list to specific way

Tags: flutter, dart, timestamp

I have List contains several `Timestamp.toDate()` like following

```
List MyList= [
2022-06-09 10:01:56.874
2022-06-09 11:02:22.874 // it has the same previous days,months but difference times
2022-06-09 12:03:22.874 // it has the same previous days,months but difference times too
2023-06-09 11:00:56.874 // it has the same previous days,months but difference Years
]
```

Now, how can I remove all elements that has the same days,months with keeping one old element of these days at least (the selected element will be the oldest time )
and the same with years
so I want the output like following

```
List MyList= [
    2022-06-09 10:01:56.874 // i will keep this element because it is old one
    2022-06-09 11:02:22.874 // i will delete this because it has same previous day and month
    2022-06-09 12:03:22.874 // i will delete this because it has same previous day and month too 
    2023-06-09 11:00:56.874 // we have here same previous days and month but i will keep it because it has difference year 
    ]
```

SO the Final

```
 List MyList= [
    2022-06-09 10:01:56.874
    2023-06-09 11:00:56.874
    ]
```

I have big List with Big elements like this
any one could tell me how to filter my list like this ? thanks

Comment: Is `MyList` of type `List<DateTime>`? That isn't entirely clear to me from the question. And is the list sorted chronologically?

Comment: Yes .. List<DateTime> .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
 List<DateTime> myList = [
    DateTime(2022, 06, 09, 10, 01),
    DateTime(2022, 06, 09, 11, 02),
    DateTime(2022, 06, 09, 12, 03),
    DateTime(2023, 06, 09, 10, 01),
  ];

  // Important that the list is sorted first.. 
  // You might be able to skip the sorting, as your list already seemed to be sorted  
  myList.sort();

  final res = myList
      .where(
        (e) => e == myList.firstWhere((f) => e.year == f.year && e.month == f.month && e.day == f.day),
      )
      .toList();

  print(myList);
  print(res);
```

Will print:

```
[2022-06-09 10:01:00.000, 2022-06-09 11:02:00.000, 2022-06-09 12:03:00.000, 2023-06-09 10:01:00.000]

[2022-06-09 10:01:00.000, 2023-06-09 10:01:00.000]
```

DartPad:

https://dartpad.dev/bc6cc0ee81d89b56eb358c12a973fafa

Comment: thanks a lot that's what i want , you hit it perfect ,, but could you please tell me how to make sure that the elements sorted from old to newest at same your example ?

Comment: Do you mean the result from newest to oldest? If so, then just do: `res.sort((a, b) => b.compareTo(a));` It is already sorted old to new...

Comment: so myList.sort(); outputs old to new as default ?

Comment: Yes. You have to just try :) Just experiment and learn :) https://dartpad.dev/d1c4251731ede3811136b22109840f54

Comment: AGAIN really thank you so mush @Robert .. i appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would give me desired outcome, although I'm not sure if there are more efficient ways to do it. This also assumes the list is sorted.

```
var result = groupBy(MyList,
        (DateTime datetime) => DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(datetime))
    .values
    .expand((element) => [element.first])
    .toList();
```

You will need these imports for the methods used here

```
 import "package:collection/collection.dart";
 import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not interested with the time part in the date, you are only interested with the date (year, month, day), so we can build the whole solution around the trick of removing the time part:

**First Step:** Convert the date to `DateTime()` objects, for example:

```
List<DateTime> dateTimes = [
  DateTime.parse('2022-06-09 10:01:56.874'),
  DateTime.parse('2022-06-09 11:02:22.874'),
  DateTime.parse('2022-06-09 12:03:22.874'),
  DateTime.parse('2023-06-09 11:00:56.874'),
];
```

**Second Step:** Remove the time part from the `dateTimes`:

```
final List<DateTime> dates = dateTimes.map((dateTime) => DateTime(dateTime.year,dateTime.month,dateTime.day)).toList();
```

**Third Step:** Define a list to hold the filtered output:

```
final List<DateTime> filteredDates = [];
```

**Fourth Step:** Loop on the `dates` list and for each date, check if it exists in the filtered list or not, if yes, then ignore it, if not, add it.

**Note that it will work because when we removed the time part from the `dateTimes` all the dates with same year, month, and day become equivalint.**

```
for (DateTime date in dates) {
  if (!filteredDates.contains(date)) {
    filteredDates.add(date);
  }
}
```

**That's it!, The Output:**

```
[2022-06-09 00:00:00.000, 2023-06-09 00:00:00.000]
```

Comment: thanks , but i do care of the Time part so based on it i can choice it as the first elements of these with the same day month from older one as a priority in my need

Comment: Hmm, though it is not important.